# apply() and calculating proportion of first row for all dataframe rows

Tags: r, rows, apply, divide

I have a dataframe as shown below listing the number of injuries by vehicle type:

```
trqldnum <- data.frame(motorveh=c(796,912,908,880,941,966,989,984),
                       motorcyc=c(257,295,326,313,403,389,474,496),
                       bicyc=c(109,127,125,137,172,146,173,178))
trqldnum

#  motorveh motorcyc bicyc
#1      796      257   109
#2      912      295   127
#3      908      326   125
#4      880      313   137
#5      941      403   172
#6      966      389   146
#7      989      474   173
#8      984      496   178
```

At the moment I am calculating a proportion of the first row for each vehicle type using:

```
trqldprop <- t(apply(trqldnum,1,function(x) {
                 x/c(trqldnum[1,1],trqldnum[1,2],trqldnum[1,3])
              }))
trqldprop

#  motorveh motorcyc    bicyc
#1 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
#2 1.145729 1.147860 1.165138
#3 1.140704 1.268482 1.146789
#4 1.105528 1.217899 1.256881
#5 1.182161 1.568093 1.577982
#6 1.213568 1.513619 1.339450
#7 1.242462 1.844358 1.587156
#8 1.236181 1.929961 1.633028
```

This seems a bit ugly and I would need to manually change the denominator of the function if the data changed shape. I end up with the output in a list of a lists if I try to just use the following within the apply() statement.

```
function(x) x/c(trqldnum[1,])
```

I'd prefer to end up with the dataframe result as above but am just getting in a muddle trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
sweep(trqldnum,2,unlist(trqldnum[1,]),"/")
```

?

The `unlist` is required to convert the first row of the data frame into a vector that can be swept ...

Answer (score 3):

Convert the data-frame to a matrix and use matrix operations:

```
m <- as.matrix(trqldnum)

trqldprop <- as.data.frame( t(t(m)/m[1,]) )

> trqldprop
  motorveh motorcyc    bicyc
1 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
2 1.145729 1.147860 1.165138
3 1.140704 1.268482 1.146789
4 1.105528 1.217899 1.256881
5 1.182161 1.568093 1.577982
6 1.213568 1.513619 1.339450
7 1.242462 1.844358 1.587156
8 1.236181 1.929961 1.633028
```

Note that we need to transpose the matrix (see the `t(m)`) because when you divide a matrix by a vector, the operation is done column-wise.

Comment: Nice answer, if I had enough reputation I would +1 you. I admit I am not very well-versed with matrix operations, so I now have a topic to read up on today.

Answer (score 3):

I like the `plyr` for these tasks as they allow you to specify the format of the output. You can turn this into a function that will scale to more columns and different base levels for the division easily.

```
FUN <- function(dat, baseRow = 1){
    require(plyr)   
    divisors <- dat[baseRow ,]
    adply(dat, 1, function(x) x / divisors)
}

FUN(trqldnum, 1)

  motorveh motorcyc    bicyc
1 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
2 1.145729 1.147860 1.165138
3 1.140704 1.268482 1.146789
4 1.105528 1.217899 1.256881
5 1.182161 1.568093 1.577982
6 1.213568 1.513619 1.339450
7 1.242462 1.844358 1.587156
8 1.236181 1.929961 1.633028
```

Answer (score 2):

Some version of Prasad solution without conversion to matrix.

```
trqldnum/trqldnum[1,][rep(1,nrow(trqldnum)),]
```

Comment: After repeating a similar analysis today, I realise that this could be simplified a little further by using...   trqldnum/trqldnum[rep(1,nrow(trqldnum)),]