# Divide all values in column, by the value from a specific row

Tags: r

I'd like to divide all the values in the column, by a value in a specific row. Here is some sample data.

```
set.seed(123)
a <- sample(1:100, 6, replace = TRUE)
b <- sample(1:100, 6, replace = TRUE)
c <- sample(1:100, 6, replace = TRUE)
d <- sample(1:100, 6, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)

df

> df
   a  b  c  d
1 31 50 69 99
2 79 43 91 72
3 51 14 57 26
4 14 25 92  7
5 67 90  9 42
6 42 91 93  9
```

I'd like all the values in each column to be divided by the value in row 1 for that column. Therefore all the values in column "a" to divided by 31, all the values in column "b" divided by 50, values in column "c" to be divided by 69, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Think this might be a duplicate of the first question I asked here nearly a decade ago! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560772/apply-and-calculating-proportion-of-first-row-for-all-dataframe-rows  memmmmmorrriieees

Comment: Seem to be a few duplicates but no one question gathers the best answers together in one place, that I've seen so far.

Comment: @thelatemail. thanks, that is useful link. I'm a R beginner, hopefully, I will make good improvements over the next decade!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could repeat the 1st row `nrow` times and divide :

```
df/df[rep(1, nrow(df)), ]

#      a    b     c      d
#1 1.000 1.00 1.000 1.0000
#2 2.548 0.86 1.319 0.7273
#3 1.645 0.28 0.826 0.2626
#4 0.452 0.50 1.333 0.0707
#5 2.161 1.80 0.130 0.4242
#6 1.355 1.82 1.348 0.0909
```

You can also use `sweep` :

```
sweep(df, 2, unlist(df[1, ]), `/`)
```